# Case sensitive issues with Mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using a legacy PHP framework which automatically assembles queries for me. By some reason, it is assembling a query like this:

```
SELECT s.status,c.client FROM client C LEFT JOIN status S ON C.id_status=S.id_status'
```

This isn't a problem on my MacOS X workstation. But when I test it on my production server  mysql raises the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 's.status' in 'field list'
```

It is definitively a case issue on s.status. If I manually runs the query changing s,c for S,C , it works perfectly.

A quick look on google didn't solved the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is case sensitivity related?

Comment: so you have a column with the same name as the table? Or is that just a typo?

Comment: Yeah, column has same name as the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's said in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on
>   Windows or Mac OS X. The following statement would not work on Unix,
>   because it refers to the alias both as a and as A:

```
mysql> SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name AS a
    -> WHERE a.col_name = 1 OR A.col_name = 2;
```

There are also some solutions given in this section of the documentation as well. For example, you can set `lower_case_table_names` to `1` on all platforms to force names to be converted to lowercase - but you have to rename all your tables to lowercase as well in that case.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that this solves my doubt. It makes sense that mysql behaves like this in Windows, but on MacOS it should behave like other Unix.

Comment: Well, Mac OS X seems to be somewhat of a mix: file-table mapping is exact (as in Unix), yet name comparisons are case-insensitive (as in Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Tables in MySQL are stored as files. File names are case-insensitive in MacOS X and Windows, whereas they are case-sensitive in Linux. You can use table names  without regarding case in MacOS X and Windows, but not in Linux. So you should choose a consistent casing for all your table names and use it throughout your code.

I'd suggest using all lowercase or uppercase names separated with underscore like `tbl_etc`, `MY_TBL` etc so that there'd be no confusion regarding case.